# meteor simple-schema fpr time-series data

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

i'm a beginner with meteor.
I' want to get a database collection in meteor for time-series data like at [MongoDb Blog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb). They have explained a Mongo Schema which should work fine for time series data.
The Collection should look like this:

```
{
  timestamp_minute: ISODate(“2013-10-10T23:06:00.000Z”),
  num_samples: 58,
  total_samples: 108000000,
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    0: 999999,
    …  
    37: 1000000,
    38: 1500000,
    … 
    59: 1800000
  }
}
```

All the fields are easy to get expect the values field.

Two question for this:

Do i have to make a own schema vor the values field?
like

```
sensorValues = new SimpleSchema ({
      0: {
          type: Number
      },
      ...,
      59: {
          type: Number
      }
})
```

second: If yes why i can't access values.0 and i have to use a string like values.value0
and have to change the schema like this?.

```
sensorValues = new SimpleSchema ({
      values0: {
          type: Number
      },
      ...,
      values59: {
          type: Number
      }
})
```

Maybe somebod can help me to get the Collection like explained at the meteor blog.

thanks for your help.

greetings
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define values as an array of numbers.

```
values: {
type: [Number]
}
```

Comment: Yes i Know. But then i can't Access them like value.0